# Building bspatch for android

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need to build bspatch.c from bsdiff-4.3 to work on an android tablet running KitKat, but I keep getting the following errors.

```
puter@radio:~/newWorkspace/AndroidCode$ $NDK_ROOT/ndk-build
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : bspatch <= bspatch.c
[armeabi] Executable     : bspatch
/home/puter/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/bspatch/bspatch.o: in function main:jni/bspatch.c:119: error: undefined reference to 'BZ2_bzReadOpen'
/home/puter/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/bspatch/bspatch.o: in function main:jni/bspatch.c:126: error: undefined reference to 'BZ2_bzReadOpen'
/home/puter/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/bspatch/bspatch.o: in function main:jni/bspatch.c:133: error: undefined reference to 'BZ2_bzReadOpen'
/home/puter/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/bspatch/bspatch.o: in function main:jni/bspatch.c:148: error: undefined reference to 'BZ2_bzRead'
/home/puter/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/bspatch/bspatch.o: in function main:jni/bspatch.c:165: error: undefined reference to 'BZ2_bzRead'
/home/puter/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/bspatch/bspatch.o: in function main:jni/bspatch.c:184: error: undefined reference to 'BZ2_bzRead'
/home/puter/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/bspatch/bspatch.o: in function main:jni/bspatch.c:195: error: undefined reference to 'BZ2_bzReadClose'
/home/puter/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/bspatch/bspatch.o: in function main:jni/bspatch.c:196: error: undefined reference to 'BZ2_bzReadClose'
/home/puter/android-ndk-r10c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/bspatch/bspatch.o: in function main:jni/bspatch.c:197: error: undefined reference to 'BZ2_bzReadClose'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/bspatch] Error 1
```

Here is my Android.mk file.

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := bspatch.c
LOCAL_MODULE := bspatch
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += /home/puter/android-ndk-r10c/sources/third_party/bzip2
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libbz2
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

This bug is documented in a number of places, e.g. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bsdiff/+bug/726338, but I still don't know how to fix it. I work as a Junior Java Developer, but have no experience with C or C++, so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for anyone with a similiar issue.
I changed my Android.mk to

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := bspatch.c bzlib.c crctable.c randtable.c decompress.c huffman.c
LOCAL_MODULE := bspatch
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := /home/puter/android-ndk-r10c/sources/third_party/bzip2/
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

and copied the source files with the methods causing the undefined errors in to the project's jni folder.

After that it builds fine

```
puter@radio:~/newWorkspace/AndroidCode$ /home/puter/android-ndk-r10c/ndk-build
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : bspatch <= bspatch.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : bspatch <= bzlib.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : bspatch <= crctable.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : bspatch <= randtable.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : bspatch <= decompress.c
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : bspatch <= huffman.c
[armeabi] Executable     : bspatch
[armeabi] Install        : bspatch => libs/armeabi/bspatch
```

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bootable/recovery.git/+/android-5.0.2_r3/applypatch/